# GITLAB(CI/CD pipeline) Unable to deploy deployment.yaml file from gitlab pipeline to aws eks cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, amazon-eks, continuous-deployment, cicd

I can able to deploy the project in locally successfully and hence the error is not related to API versions I believe but in the gitlab pipeline getting the below error.

$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: roffe/kubectl
 
  script:
    - kubectl config set-cluster k8s --server="${kubernetes_server}"
    - kubectl config set clusters.k8s.certificate-authority-data "${Certificate_authority}"
    - kubectl config set-credentials gitlab --token="${gitlab_access_token}"
    - kubectl config set-context default --cluster=k8s --user=root
    - kubectl config use-context default
    - cat deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
    - kubectl get deployments
    - kubectl apply -f service.yaml
    - kubectl get services
```

deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-demo
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 33%
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: ***************.com/sampledatetime:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

I have tried the gitlab project that contains deployment.yaml and gitlab-ci.yml for aws eks cluster deployment.

Deployment should happen via gitlab-ci/cd to aws eks cluster.